# Django Form Wizard Skip Multiple Steps with Conditional Logic

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Is there some way to skip multiple steps in Django's Form Wizard (i.e. SessionWizardView)?

I know it is possible to use condition_dict to produce the following form display logic:
Page 1 -> Page 3

```
#urls.py 
path('main/', MyWizard.as_view(set_of_forms, condition_dict={'1': view_condition} ))
```

What I would like to do is the following:
Page 1 --> Page 4

Presumably, adding a condition_dict based on the content of Page 1 should work to skip Page 3, but it doesn't work. For example:

```
#urls.py 
path('main/', MyWizard.as_view(set_of_forms, condition_dict={'1': view_condition, '2': view_condition2,} ))
```

I am truly stumped on how to crack this nut. Any guidance that you can provide would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to specify when FormWizard skips a step is to use a condition_dictionary. Django uses the structure to only include the form for a step when the conditions (set as callables)

```
# I always specify index values for steps so that all functions can share them
STEP_ONE = u'0'
STEP_TWO = u'1'
STEP_THREE = u'2'


def MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    # Your form wizard itself; will not be called directly by urls.py, but rather wrapped in a function that provide the condition_dictionary
    _condition_dict = { # a dictionary with key=step, value=callable function that return True to show step and False to not
        STEP_ONE: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
        STEP_TWO: check_step_two, # conditional callable for verifying whether to show step two
        STEP_THREE: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
    }
    _form_list = [ # a list of forms used per step
        (STEP_ONE,your_forms.StepOneForm),
        (STEP_TWO, your_forms.StepTwoForm),
        (STEP_THREE, your_forms.StepThreeForm),
    ]
    ...


def return_true(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
    return True # a condition that is always True, for when you always want form seen

def check_step_two(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
    step_1_info = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(STEP_ONE)
    # do something with info; can retrieve for any prior steps
    if step_1_info == some_condition:
        return True # show step 2
    else: return False # or don't

''' urls.py '''

your_form_wizard = MyWizard.as_view(MyWizard._form_list,condition_dict= MyWizard._condition_dict)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^form_wizard_url/$', your_form_wizard, name='my-form-wizard',) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @PauloRodrigues! Your answer is very clear and very helpful. I have reposted your answer with some minor changes indicating how multiple steps can be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Paulo, for your answer! This is exactly what is needed to easily skip form pages. Building on Paulo's answer, three changes need to be made to skip *multiple* steps simultaneously:

```
# I always specify index values for steps so that all functions can share them
STEP_ONE = u'0'
STEP_TWO = u'1'
STEP_THREE = u'2'


def MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    # Your form wizard itself; will not be called directly by urls.py, but rather wrapped in a function that provide the condition_dictionary

    # **Change1**: functions need to be stated before the dictionary
    def return_true(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
        return True # a condition that is always True, for when you always want form seen

    # **Change 2:** Only proceed with the logic if the step is valid
    def check_step_two(wizard): #  callable function called in _condition_dict
        step_1_info = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(STEP_ONE)
        # do something with info; can retrieve for any prior steps
        if step_1_info != None:
            if step_1_info == some_condition:
                return True # show step 2
            else: return False # or don't

     # **Change 3**: a condition must be added to skip an additional form
    _condition_dict = { # a dictionary with key=step, value=callable function that return True to show step and False to not
        STEP_ONE: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
        STEP_TWO: check_step_two, # conditional callable for verifying whether to show step two
        STEP_THREE: check_step_two, # conditional callable for verifying whether to show step three
        STEP_FOUR: return_true, # callable function that says to always show this step
    }
    _form_list = [ # a list of forms used per step
        (STEP_ONE,your_forms.StepOneForm),
        (STEP_TWO, your_forms.StepTwoForm),
        (STEP_THREE, your_forms.StepThreeForm),
        (STEP_THREE, your_forms.StepFourForm),
    ]
    ...

''' urls.py '''

your_form_wizard = MyWizard.as_view(MyWizard._form_list,condition_dict= MyWizard._condition_dict)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^form_wizard_url/$', your_form_wizard, name='my-form-wizard',) 
)
```